# Django querysets - Performing subqueries

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

How to make query to get all components added by a certain user? Also in the resulting object I want to have the system name and project name too. I saw examples demonstrating sub-queries for two tables, but I need this for 3 tables.
Thank you.

```
class component(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    server = models.ForeignKey(server, on_delete="CASCADE")
    name = models.TextField(blank=True)
    comments = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class system(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(project, on_delete="CASCADE")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    comments = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    comments = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete="CASCADE")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: So you want the components that belong to a system that belongs to a project that belongs to a user, right?

Comment: Components of all the systems in all the projects of a user. The system name and project name should also be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use *subqueries* here, we can simply perform joins, by looking "through" foreign keys (this is typically denoted with two consecutive underscores `__` in Django).

If you want So all the `Component`s that belong to a `System` that belongs to a `Project` that belongs to a `user`, we can query this with:

```
from django.db.models import F

Component.objects.filter(
    system__project__user=someuser
).annotate(
    system_name=F('system__name'),
    project_name=F('system__project__name')
)
```

with `someuser` the user you want to filter with.

The components in this queryset will have extra attributes `system_name` and `project_name` that contain the name of the system and the project respectively.

Comment: Thank you. That did the job.